# Bounding an absolute value of a determinant of a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given an integer $n>3$ and a string of positive real numbers $b_1>\ldots>b_m$, where $m=2n-1$, the matrix $A=\{a_{ij}\}^n_{i,j=1}$ is defined with
$$a_{ij} = b_{i+j-1}$$
What can we say about $\det A$ in this case? Is there a general condition on $\{b_i\}$ that would lead to $\det A = 0$? Is there a way to bound $|\det A|$ with something reasonable that depends on $\{b_i\}$?